# Remove multiple elements from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a bunch of indexes and I want to remove elements at these indexes from an `ArrayList`. I can't do a simple sequence of `remove()`s because the elements are shifted after each removal. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Sort the indices in descending order and then remove them one by one.  If you do that, there's no way a remove will affect any indices that you later want to remove.

How you sort them will depend on the collection you are using to store the indices.  If it's a list, you can do this:

```
List<Integer> indices;
Collections.sort(indices, new Comparator<Integer>() {
   public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
      //todo: handle null
      return b.compareTo(a);
   }
}
```

### Edit

@aioobe found the helper that I failed to find.  Instead of the above, you can use

```
Collections.sort(indices, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: No need to reinvent the reverse reverse comparator. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950678/remove-multiple-elements-from-arraylist/4950905#4950905).

Comment: @aioobe:Thanks, I thought there was a way to do it within the Collections API but I was having trouble finding it.

Comment: Arrays.sort() if you have an array ^^

Comment: I don't understand. In what way does sorting an array change the fact that things need to be shifted? For example, if the array was `{ 8, 5, 9, 1, 4, 7 }` The user wants to remove `1`, `5`,  and `4`. If you reverse sort the array to: `{ 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 1 }` you are no closer to accomplishing your goal.

Comment: @Hatefiend: I didn't say to sort the *values*, I said sort the *indices*.  So in your example, the indices would be 1, 3, 4.  Sorted would be [4, 3, 1].  Removing them in that order means that the indices of subsequent removals will still be valid.  After removing 4 (at index 4), 5 and 1 will still be at index 1 and 3 respectively.  And so on.

Answer (score 50):

To remove elements at `indexes`:

```
Collections.sort(indexes, Collections.reverseOrder());
for (int i : indexes)
    strs.remove(i);
```

Or, using the Stream API from Java 8:

```
indexes.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
indexes.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).forEach(l::remove);
```

Comment: Arrays.sort() if dealing with arrays ^^

Answer (score 20):

I came here for removing elements in specific range (i.e., all elements between 2 indexes), and found this:

```
list.subList(indexStart, indexEnd).clear()
```

Comment: The subList() method of java.util.ArrayList class is used to return a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.)

The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports all of the optional list operations.

Comment: this works because structural changes apparently also are reflected in the backing list via the protected removeRange method. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65005722/1527469

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the elements starting from the largest index downwards, or if you have references to the objects you wish to remove, you can use the [removeAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method.

Answer (score 4):

you might want to use the [subList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)) method  with the range of index you would like to remove and
then call clear() on it.

(pay attention that the second parameter is exclusive - for example in this case, I pass 2  meaning only index 0 and 1 will be removed.):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
    animals.add("cow");
    animals.add("dog");
    animals.add("chicken");
    animals.add("cat");
    animals.subList(0, 2).clear();
    for(String s : animals)
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

}

the result will be:
chicken
cat

Comment: thanks! this is a good List range operation to get a subList from a List. documentation for the method -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int, int)

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the indexes in reverse order. If the indexes are in order like 1,2,3 you can do [removeRange](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeRange%28int,%20int%29)(1, 3).

Comment: It seems not possible to use the `removeRange` method as long as you don't extend `ArrayList`, because the method is `protected`.

Comment: @SanghyunLee Why it is `protected` though ?

Answer (score 2):

I think nanda was the correct answer.

```
List<T> toRemove = new LinkedList<T>();
for (T t : masterList) {
  if (t.shouldRemove()) {
    toRemove.add(t);
  }
}

masterList.removeAll(toRemove);
```

Comment: This is a poor solution. Better to use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the indices as many said, or you can use an iterator and call remove()

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("0");
    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");
    list.add("4");
    list.add("5");
    list.add("6");
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    indexes.add(2);
    indexes.add(5);
    indexes.add(3);
    int cpt = 0;
    Iterator<String> it = list.iterator(); 
    while(it.hasNext()){
        it.next();
        if(indexes.contains(cpt)){
            it.remove();
        }
        cpt++;
    }
```

it depends what you need, but the sort will be faster in most cases

Comment: I just had a case where I could eliminate the list of indexes, because they where a workaround to remember the rows to remove. Iterator.remove is cool and can solve some remove problems easily and fast.

Answer (score 1):

Use [guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/)! The method you are looking is **Iterators.removeAll(Iterator removeFrom, Collection elementsToRemove)**

Comment: I think he has indices, not the real elements. So this is not helping imo.

Answer (score 1):

If you have really many elements to remove (and a long list), it may be faster to iterate over the list and add all elements who are not to be removed to a new list, since each `remove()`-step in a array-list copies all elements after the removed one by one. In this case, if you index list is not already sorted (and you can iterate over it parallel to the main list), you may want to use a HashSet or BitSet or some similar O(1)-access-structure for the `contains()` check:

```
/**
 * creates a new List containing all elements of {@code original},
 * apart from those with an index in {@code indices}.
 * Neither the original list nor the indices collection is changed.
 * @return a new list containing only the remaining elements.
 */
public <X> List<X> removeElements(List<X> original, Collection<Integer> indices) {
    // wrap for faster access.
    indices = new HashSet<Integer>(indices);
    List<X> output = new ArrayList<X>();
    int len = original.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       if(!indices.contains(i)) {
           output.add(original.get(i));
       }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

order your list of indexes, like this

if 2,12,9,7,3 order desc to 12,9,7,3,2

and then do this

`for(var i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++)
{
 source_array.remove(indexes[0]);
}`

this should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements you wish to remove are all grouped together, you can do a `subList(start, end).clear()` operation.

If the elements you wish to remove are scattered, it may be better to create a new ArrayList, add only the elements you wish to include, and then copy back into the original list.

Edit: I realize now this was not a question of performance but of logic.

Comment: .clear() returns void (in typical java fashion)...how would you retain your sublist (if you needed to)

Comment: @Jason
List sublist = list.subList(start, end);

List removed = new List(subList);

subList.clear();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove positions X to the Size

```
//a is the ArrayList
a=(ArrayList)a.sublist(0,X-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `indexes` array is sorted (eg: 1, 3, 19, 29), you can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < indexes.size(); i++){
   originalArray.remove(indexes.get(i) - i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient method that I guess I have not seen above is creating a new Arraylist and selecting which indices survive by copying them to the new array. And finally reassign the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here for a similar query and @aioobe's answer helped me figure out the solution.
However, if you are populating the list of indices to delete yourself, might want to consider using [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(int,%20E)):

```
indices.add(0, i);
```

This will eliminate the need for (the costly) reverse-sorting of the list before iterating over it, while removing elements from the main ArrayList.