# List<String>.remove does not appear to be working properly

Tags: java

I am developing in Java on Netbeans IDE 7.4 on Windows 7.  I am using the following code to progressively remove and shift elements in a list of strings.

```
static void RemoveSubsequence(List<String> entries, int start, int end){
    int removeIndex=start+1;
    String debugStr;
    for (int i=removeIndex; i<end; ++i){
        debugStr=entries.remove(removeIndex);
    } 
}
```

The following are the results for 13 elements in the list starting with index removeIndex.  The first column shows the initial values while the next two columns shows the results of the first two iterations.  The first iteration works perfectly but the second iteration changes what should be 624 (second row) to 634.

```
634 624 624
624 624 634
624 624 634
624 634 624
634 624 634
624 634 624
634 624 634
624 634 776
634 776 672
776 672 624
672 624 776
624 776 776
776 776 672
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with NetBeans

Comment: Your code seems to be working here. How did you get your columns?

Comment: You might consider using an Iterator instead of a for loop.  If removing items while looping, it's the way to go.

Comment: How are you calling this method to remove the first element... I'm wondering why you are adding 1 to the remove index..?

Comment: @Java Devil.  I wanted to start removing elements from the first element after the start.  (I subsequently replace the element at the start index with something else.)

Comment: I see where the problem is.  I accidentally put the same indexed variable twice in the NetBeans Variables window.  Sorry about that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950678/remove-multiple-elements-from-arraylist has a discussion directly related to this which may be of interest & use to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i understand what you are intending to do now, sorry.

If you want to remove a subset of the list, what you should do is keep removing the item at index "Start", and remove that same index "End - Start" times.

int times = end - start;

For (int i= 0; i < times; i++)
{
   String listItem = list.remove(start);
}

Now your list has removed all the required items.

Comment: I tried that and got the same results.  However, I did notice that the problem had gone away (the bogus 634 had returned to 624).

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the entry from the List first, and then assign the string value of debugStr. See if that helps.

Comment: debugStr is the value I am trying to remove with each iteration.  I would like the strings with higher indices to move to fill the gap.  Thanks,