# Need to Remove From List at Specified Multiple Indices, without new-size problems

Tags: java, for-loop

I have an array of indices at which elements must be removed from a List, e.g.: (4), (7), (8).

The problem is:

1) Can't use a For-loop, the size changes after each delete (`ArrayList.remove(i)`)

2) Can't use an Iterator with an updated counter, the counter will also not work anymore (`Iterator.remove()`).

Answer (score 0):

Found a nice solution here: [Remove multiple elements from ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950678/remove-multiple-elements-from-arraylist)

```
Collections.sort(indices, Collections.reverseOrder());
for (int i : indices)
    strs.remove(i);
```

That seems to be the only fast and simple solution. Reverse-sort first, then go through the indices and remove.