# How does SubList.clear() deletes only sublist items from "original" list?

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist, iterator

I have read the src code of *ArrayList*
I saw that class *SubList* has member thas is name : *parentOffset* and *indexOffset*.
But I have looked at function *clear()* which is inherited from *AbstractList* and found:

```
public void clear() {
    removeRange(0, size());
}

protected void removeRange(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    ListIterator<E> it = listIterator(fromIndex);
    for (int i=0, n=toIndex-fromIndex; i<n; i++) {
        it.next();
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

I can't see anyplace when the *parentOffset* is involved, and therefore can't understand how working with the backed list can clear the suit item in "parent" list?

In addition i'm going over the source code of *ListIterator* and can't understand why an exception is thrown when removing an item via iterator while running over the list?
I tried to read an explanation in the following link:[role of modcount](https://programmer.group/the-role-of-modcount-in-arraylist.html)
But unfortunately it didn't help me.

Comment: There is no direct need to use parentOffset when you still know where the sublist starts and ende. Also have you seen that `listIterator(..)` is overridden?

Comment: @Tom, it seems that the "iteration" start in index 0 instead of in the offset index. In addition  *ListIterator* is an interface so of course it is being override

Comment: "Index 0" doesn't mean that the SubList will ignore its internal offset. That's what the overridden ListIterator does. **"In addition ListIterator is an interface so of course it is being override"** then why do you ignore its implementation for SubList?

Comment: @Tom, I see. Thank you. I'm curious does it hard to understand java src code, or i'm the only one who feel so weak when trying to understand it?

Comment: It depends on your experience. If you're quite new, then it is quite hard to read advanced code from someone else. When you gain more experience, then you'll it will become easier to read and to understand code written by someone else. It is also really useful to read questions here on Stack Overflow and to work on answers. This will force you to read code from many different people and you'll get more experienced that way.

Comment: @Tom, I will defiantly try. Thank you. Do you think that the question about removing item while running  over an *Iterator* I should post as a new question?

Comment: It is a new question, so it should be posted as one, yes. But make sure to research first, that this hasn't been asked and answered before.

Comment: @Yes but I didn't understand the answer, so maybe I will explain what is hard for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking at are wrapper methods.

Imagine I ask you to make a cake. You know cake requires some flour, so... you ask your friend to go get you some, and then you bake your cake.

You're the person asking: "How the heck did you make that cake?? I never saw you buy any flour!".

`clear()` doesn't do the work. Clear asks its friend to do it: Its friend is `removeRange`.

removeRange then does the work by asking a few questions from ITS friend, which is `listIterator()`.

`it.remove()` ends up calling the remove method on that listIterator that `listIterator(fromIndex)` makes. That code does the actual heavy lifting*.

*) Or it invokes a friend too. More generally, there is no one method that does it all, because removeRange does do some of the work: It turned the job of 'delete a range' into a job of 'iterate over a range' + 'remove the element we just iterated over'.

Comment: but listIterator is being called with parameter *startIndex = 0*, if it was started with the offset (the index where the sublist is start), I didn't have a question here :)

Comment: But `listIterator` itself is a method of SubList (SubList overrides it!) and also has access to the `parentOffset` field, and it DOES use it (or it asks a friend too, but eventually you'll get to a friend that uses that field).